# Can't run docker-machine create, VBoxManage not found

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, docker

I had the following problem when trying to do a `docker-compose up`:

```
[10:46:31] coil@coil:~/workspace/docker$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.

[10:48:00] coil@coil:~/workspace/docker$ docker-machine start default
Docker machine "default" does not exist. Use "docker-machine ls" to list machines. Use "docker-machine create" to add a new one.

[10:57:07] coil@coilZ240:~/workspace/docker$ sudo docker-machine create default
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

[11:00:17] coil@coilZ240:~/workspace/docker$ VBoxManage -v 
5.2.18_Ubuntur123745
```

This is weird as VBoxManage is already in the path and can be launched.

Current versions are:

- Ubuntu: 18.04.01
- Docker: 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
- docker-machine: 0.15.0, build b48dc28
- VBoxManage: 5.2.18_Ubuntur123745

I installed Docker some time ago with a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/docker). Can you confirm that the following [official installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) is the way to go? Or is the snap version ok?

Comment: I just clicked on the Ubuntu Software. I would assume this is the "Official" Download.

Comment: It is indeed a snap installation: `/snap/bin/docker`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer. Don't use the snap. I reinstalled everything using [the official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) and it works now.

Comment: I just used the official instruction guide and I'm still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question.
but my OS is Linux Mint 19.

I to do this solution solve my question

update  docker-machine to version 0.16.0, build 702c267f .

reference

[VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path](https://www.servloci.com/vboxmanage-not-found-make-sure-virtualbox-is-installed-and-vboxmanage-is-in-the-path/)

[Install Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your user is in the docker group. Otherwise you run docker as root and vbox as user and they can't see each other. Telltale sign that you're not in the group is that you have to sudo docker commands, e.g.:

```
sudo docker images
```

To fix, do:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a <your-username> docker
```

Now check that user is added:

```
getent group docker
```

or:

```
grep /etc/group -e "docker"
```

Also restart docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Log out and back into terminal (try restarting system if this does not work), and you should be able to run docker without sudo, e.g.:

```
docker images
```

docker machine and docker-compose should now run, too.

Fore more information, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101043/cant-connect-to-docker-from-docker-compose

Comment: Thanks! running `docker-compose` with` sudo` priveleges worked

Comment: @NuryagdyMustapayev you generally should not run docker as sudo. Adding yourself to the docker group as described in the post above is the correct approach. Running docker as sudo will potentially cause other access issues, and isn't recommended.